# Adding QTextEdit to QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I have a block of text in my QTextEdit area but it is too big for the area. I have tried adding the textArea to a QScrollArea to enable me to scroll through the text. I am wondering where I am going wrong with this as it does not seem to do anything. I am wondering what is the correct thing to do. Here is my code with the outputted stack trace.

```
# Import Statements
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from MainGuiWindow import Ui_MainWindow

# Main Class that holds User Interface Objects
class Ui_informationWindow(object):

    # Function for Opening Main GUI window from login window by clicking login button
    def openMainWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        loginWindow.hide()
        self.window.show()

    def setupUi(self, informationWindow):
        informationWindow.setObjectName("User Information Window")
        informationWindow.setFixedSize(393, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(informationWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        informationWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: Cornflowerblue")

        # Proceed button
        self.proceedButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.proceedButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 250, 101, 27))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.proceedButton.setFont(font)
        self.proceedButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.proceedButton.setObjectName("proceedButton")



        # passwordTF
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 350, 230))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("informationTF")
        informationWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(loginWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 393, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        informationWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(informationWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: White")

        # Set Scroll Area
        self.textEdit.append("This is an information manual to guide users through the use of the software.")
        self.textEdit.append("\n")
        self.textEdit.append("To use this software, the user must first parse the data from each evidence item which will store the data in Microsoft Excel table format in an external directory")
        self.textEdit.append("In turn, the corresponding report generation options will become available one by one to enable report generation for that piece of evidence.")
        self.textEdit.append("\n")
        self.textEdit.append("Once each report has been generated, the user can then view a single report for one piece of evidence or view a full report containing all parsed evidence.")
        self.textEdit.append("\n")
        self.textEdit.append("These reports, much like the parsed forensic data are stored in a Forensic Reports directory.")
        self.textEdit.append("\n")
        self.textEdit.append("Please press the Proceed button to begin using the software.")
        self.textEdit.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit.setEnabled(False)

        # This is where I am trying to put the textEdit text into a scrollArea to make it scrollable
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBar(self.textEdit)

        informationWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        self.retranslateUi(informationWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(informationWindow)

    # Function that sets the text on all the UI Buttons
    def retranslateUi(self, loginWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        loginWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("informationWindow", "User Manual"))
        self.proceedButton.setText(_translate("informationWindow", "Proceed"))

    # Event Handling Code Section

        # Event Handling to open Main GUI Window
        self.proceedButton.clicked.connect(self.openMainWindow)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loginWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_informationWindow()
    ui.setupUi(loginWindow)
    loginWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Stack Trace

```
self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBar(self.textEdit)
TypeError: QAbstractScrollArea.setVerticalScrollBar(QScrollBar): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QTextEdit'
```

Comment: why `self.textEdit.setEnabled(False)`?

Comment: I dont want anyone to be able to edit the text once the window loads

Comment: Look at my answer, you are using the inadequate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTextEdit` already has a `QScrollBar` so you should not add any, if you want the text not to be editable you should use `setReadOnly(True)` instead of `setEnabled(False)`.

```
# passwordTF
self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
[...]
self.textEdit.setFont(font)
self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
```

Comment: Perfect. It is working now. I will keep in mind that it should be setReadOnly(True) in future. Thanks

Comment: I will :D. It is just telling me I have to wait 2 mins before accepting the answer.